# Using TouchesBegan to stop animation in viewDidAppear Swift

Tags: swift, animation, touchesbegan, viewdidappear

I am new to Swift and I would like to use `touchesBegan` to stop all animations from `viewDidAppear`, but it did not work both of remove `self.view.layer.removeAllAnimatoins()` and speed up animations.

I do this by putting `self.view.layer.removeAllAnimatoins()` inside of `touchesBegan` and then set all alpha to normal.

Like this,

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()

    self.btnO.alpha = 1.0
    self.btnX.alpha = 1.0

    self.titleMultiplayer.alpha = 1.0

    self.questionOX.alpha = 1.0
}
```

And this is another code by speeding up animations,

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class ViewController: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet var titleMultiplayer: UILabel!

     @IBOutlet var questionOX: UILabel!

     @IBOutlet var btnO: UIButton!
     @IBOutlet var btnX: UIButton!


     override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
         super.viewWillAppear(animated)

         titleMultiplayer.alpha = 0.0

         questionOX.alpha = 0.0

         btnO.alpha = 0.0
         btnX.alpha = 0.0

     }

     override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

         UIView.animateWithDuration(0.001, animations: {

             self.titleMultiplayer.alpha = 1.0

             self.btnO.alpha = 1.0
             self.btnX.alpha = 1.0

             self.questionOX.alpha = 1.0

         })


     }


     override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
         super.viewDidAppear(animated)



         UIView.animateWithDuration(4.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {

             self.titleMultiplayer.alpha = 1.0

            }, completion: nil)


        UIView.animateWithDuration(4.0, delay: 2.3, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {

            self.btnO.alpha = 1.0

            }, completion: nil)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(4.0, delay: 4.3, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {

            self.btnX.alpha = 1.0

            }, completion: nil)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(4.0, delay: 6.3, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {

            self.questionOX.alpha = 1.0

            }, completion: nil)



     }

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



     }
```

I wonder if it is possible to do something like this with `viewDidAppear`.

Please help and suggest me.

Thank you very much :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the current animation from the UI component's layer with `removeAllAnimations()`, and then you can do whatever else you want.

In your case you can remove animation this way in your `touchesBegan` method:

```
btnO.layer.removeAllAnimations()
btnX.layer.removeAllAnimations()
titleMultiplayer.layer.removeAllAnimations()
questionOX.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

You can remove the current animation from the UI component's layer with `removeAllAnimations`, and then you can do whatever else you want.